# Can I get 'Lion/Windows-like' window resizing in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I'm using Snow Leopard, and I'm finding it unbelievably frustrating that I can only resize windows using a single corner. Is there something I can install that will let me resize any window with any edge/corner?

Comment: Just curious, what's preventing you from upgrading to Lion?

Comment: I'm developing on Snow Leopard, for backwards compatibility. I have no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have seen to do this in Snow Leopard is through the addition of an application such as [Right Zoom](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30591/right-zoom) or [Mega Zoomer](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21275/megazoomer). Until you can move to Lion it seems this is your primary option unless you want to write your own scripts to do it.

---

Alrighty then, resize from any corner. You may want to take a look at [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/). May not be EXACTLY it but it claims that you can resize a window from anywhere. [Zooom](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/index_green/index.html)

Comment: Right Zoom is good, but it's not solving the problem I have (being able to tweak the window size by dragging an edge).

Comment: Check out the edit and see how those work for you.

Comment: I installed afloat, it doesn't do what I want at all! It seems to be all about making windows transparent, nowhere can I find, in the documentation or otherwise, a way of enabling resizing from any edge!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an application like [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom) or [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) if you want to resize the windows via hotkeys, but I haven't seen an any-edge resizing solution.